# Strange issue by getting NSImage from the absolute path of the file

Tags: swift, macos

It's really strange and weird. I've tried every option but I still get `nil` when I try to get `NSImage` by the absolute or relative path of the file.

I've tried next:

```
let desctopImagePath = NSWorkspace.shared.desktopImageURL(for: mainScreen)?.relativePath.removingPercentEncoding
let desctopImage = try NSImage(byReferencingFile: desctopImagePath)
```

or

```
NSImage(byReferencing: URL(fileURLWithPath: desctopImagePath))

NSImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: desctopImagePath))

NSImage(contentsOfFile: desctopImagePath)

NSImage(contentsOf: URL(string: desctopImagePath))
```

from each case I get `nil`. The path is correct. I've tried to find it via `Finder` with `Command + Shift + G` - it works.

What is happening here and what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `relativePath` and `removingPercentEncoding`. Just use the URL related API whenever possible.

There are two different cases

- If you are using one fixed image `desktopImageURL(for` returns the image URL

  ```
    if let mainScreen = NSScreen.main,
        let desktopImageFolderURL = NSWorkspace.shared.desktopImageURL(for: mainScreen) {
        let image = NSImage(contentsOf: desktopImageFolderURL)
    }
  ```
- If you are using the `Change Picture` option `desktopImageURL(for` returns the URL of a directory containing alias files of the used image(s). You have to get the files in the folder

  ```
    if let mainScreen = NSScreen.main,
        let desktopImageFolderURL = NSWorkspace.shared.desktopImageURL(for: mainScreen) {
        do {
            let desktopImageURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: desktopImageFolderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            if let firstImage = desktopImageURLs.first {
                let image = NSImage(contentsOf: firstImage)
            }
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
  ```

Comment: I still get `nil`. For more information: My URL is: `file:///Users/username/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Retouched/APC_1546-Edit1.png`

Comment: What is your setting in System Preferences > Desktop & Screensaver?

Comment: For the second case I got this error: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “APC_1546-Edit1.png” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/username/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Retouched/APC_1546-Edit1.png, NSFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Retouched/APC_1546-Edit1.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c52f10 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}}`

Comment: The second case is only valid if the `Change Picture` checkbox is checked in the desktop picture settings.

Comment: I've just updated my question and added the screenshot of my System Preferences

Comment: This is Mojave beta (10.14), isn't it? And this looks like a custom picture. You should have given this information, it's important. I don't use Mojave yet.

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that it's important. I just have a path of the image and want to display it in my app

Comment: The image URL is in iCloud so the URL might be treated differently from regular local URLs.

Comment: I've tried it with `Desktop` also but it still returns `nil`